# How to set y-scale when making a boxplot with dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a column of data with a very large distribution and thus I log2-transform it before plotting and visualizing it. This works fine but I cannot seem to figure out how to set the y-scale to the exponential values of 2 (instead I have just the exponents themselves).

```
df['num_ratings_log2'] = df['num_ratings'] + 1
df['num_ratings_log2'] = np.log2(df['num_ratings_log2'])
df.boxplot(column = 'num_ratings_log2', figsize=(10,10))
```

[image]

As the scale, I would like to have 1 (2^0), 32 (2^5), 1024 (2^1) ... instead of 0, 5, 10 ...

I want everything else about the plot to stay the same. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of taking the log of the data, you can create a normal boxplot and then set a log scale on the y-axis (`ax.set_yscale('log')`, or [`symlog`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/scales/symlog_demo.html) to also represent zero). To get the ticks at powers of 2 (instead of powers of 10), use a [`LogLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.LogLocator) with base 2. A [`ScalarFormatter`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter) shows the values as regular numbers (instead of as powers such as 2<sup>10</sup>). A [`NullLocator`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/ticker_api.html#matplotlib.ticker.NullLocator) for the minor ticks suppresses undesired extra ticks.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter, LogLocator, NullLocator
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(123)
df = pd.DataFrame({'num_ratings': (np.random.pareto(10, 10000) * 800).astype(int)})
ax = df.boxplot(column='num_ratings', figsize=(10, 10))
ax.set_yscale('symlog')  # symlog also allows zero
# ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())  # show tick labels as regular numbers
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, p: f'{int(x):,}')
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(NullLocator())  # remove minor ticks
plt.show()
```

[image: boxlplot with logscale base 2]

Comment: Great this works pretty well. Only thing extra I had to do was change `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(ScalarFormatter())` to `ax.get_yaxis().set_major_formatter(matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(int(x), ',')))` as to avoid the scientific notation that gets outputted and causes many of the ticks to be '0.0'

Comment: Well, you didn't provide test data, so it is hard to guess you have values between 0 and 1.  Note that with the latest matplotlib the `FuncFormatter` can be replaced by `ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(lambda x, p: f'{int(x):,}')`

Comment: yeah that's on me. Should have at least specified the range of values. Thanks for the help!

Comment: oh it wasnt that i had values between 0 and 1 it was that i had values as high as 2^22. So matplotlib would put scientific notation such that all the ticks were to be x1e6. This caused the lower tick values (~2^0 to 2^8) to be set to 0.0 since it wouldn't should more decimal places.

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for below,

Code

```
ax = df.boxplot(column='num_ratings_log2', figsize=(20,10))
ymin = 0
ymax = 20
ax.set_ylim(2**ymin, 2**ymax)
```